# Teething bug in system MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

In an old legacy based system we make updates to a users inventory. The inventory contains many different items, user will have one row per item id and in each row is a quantity of this item that they own.

Now somewhere in this rather old and behemoth like code is a problem whereby a user can end up with a minus quantity of an item. This should never happen.

Rather than approaching the problem from the top and going through each piece of code that interacts with the inventory table we thought we might try and create some reporting to help us find the problems.

Before I go about implementing something that I think may solve this problem I thought i'd put it out there to the community to find out how they might approach it.

Perhaps could start by creating on update MySQL rules which insert activities into another table for closer inspection etc. Be creative.

Comment: Although `old legacy based system` screams no, I have to ask, does your system use a database class that you can extend?

Comment: Depending on _how_ "legacy" and how long you need to support it in the future, you might just create a trigger that zeros out negative values on `UPDATE`.  In other words, sweep it under the rug if there's any chance of being able to replace the thing in the future.

Comment: Cheers for the suggestions guys. Unfortunately, due to financial reasons, we have to stick with this legacy code base a little longer. It has a DB class, which use mysqli class so it's not too terrible.

Answer (score 1):

If you add a timestamp field then you'll know when the last operation was carried out - from that, you could find te update entry in the mysql log and possibly reconcile with the application logs.

Alternatively you could set a trigger on the table...

```
CREATE TRIGGER no_negatives_in_yourtable
BEFORE UPDATE ON yourtable
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF (NEW.value<0) THEN
     /* log it (NB will be rolled back if subsequent statement enabled */
     INSERT INTO badthings (....) VALUES (...);
     /* this forces the operation to fail */
     DROP TABLE `less than zero value in yourtable`;
  END IF;
END
```

Comment: The trigger is exactly what I was personally thinking. If I coupled that with an extra parameter which identifies where the call was made from, from within the application then we could be onto a winner.

Comment: One thing that does worry me is that it's not so much a problem with the code but with the speed of requests being fired at that db.

Comment: If you can identify all the places that the the value is updated from (in order to inject an identifier), then you can capture the event higher in the stack to find or *why*it's doing that and fix the problem rather than just measuring it.